# Можно ли по другому сделать кнопки для калькулятора?

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-events, click

Делаю калькулятор и весь код рабочий, но хотел бы узнать, можно ли как-нибудь по другому(более компактно) оформить функцию нажатия кнопок.

```js
let digitsField = document.getElementById("digit-field");

// buttons
let clear = document.getElementById("AC");
let plusOrMinus = document.getElementById("plusMinus");
let percent = document.getElementById("percent");
let divide = document.getElementById("divide");

let seven = document.getElementById("seven");
let eight = document.getElementById("eight");
let nine = document.getElementById("nine");
let multiple = document.getElementById("multiple");

let four = document.getElementById("four");
let five = document.getElementById("five");
let six = document.getElementById("six");
let minus = document.getElementById("seven");

let one = document.getElementById("one");
let two = document.getElementById("two");
let three = document.getElementById("three");
let plus = document.getElementById("plus");

let zero = document.getElementById("zero");
let comma = document.getElementById("comma");
let equal = document.getElementById("equal");

let forNumbers = document.getElementById("forNumbers");

// Вот это хочу оформить компактнее

one.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "1";
});

two.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "2";
});

three.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "3";
});

four.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "4";
});

five.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "5";
});

six.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "6";
});

seven.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "7";
});

eight.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "8";
});

nine.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "9";
});

zero.addEventListener("click", () => {
  forNumbers.textContent += "0";
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #7bb9ff;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.calculator {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#digit-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

#buttons-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.row-1, .row-2, .row-3, .row-4, .row-5 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 147px;
}

.calc-btns {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(157, 255, 206);
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.calc-btns:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

#forNumbers {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles//styles.css" />
    <title>Caclucator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">
      <h1 id="header">MY CACLUCATOR</h1>
      <div class="calculator">
        <div id="digit-field"><span id="forNumbers"></span></div>
        <div id="buttons-field">
          <div class="row-1">
            <button class="calc-btns" id="AC">AC</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="plusMinus">+/-</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="percent">%</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="divide">/</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-2">
            <button class="calc-btns" id="seven">7</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="eight">8</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="nine">9</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="multiple">X</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-3">
            <button class="calc-btns" id="four">4</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="five">5</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="six">6</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="minus">-</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-4">
            <button class="calc-btns" id="one">1</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="two">2</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="three">3</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="plus">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-5">
            <button class="calc-btns" id="zero">0</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="comma">,</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="equal">=</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: CACLUCATOR -> CALCULATOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы добавил кнопкам `data` атрибуты, и повесил слушатель события на блок с кнопками

```js
const $buttonsField = document.getElementById('buttons-field')
const $forNumbers = document.getElementById('forNumbers')

$buttonsField.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const actionNode = e.target.closest('[data-action]')
  const valueNode = e.target.closest('[data-value]')

  if (actionNode) {
    return doAction(actionNode.dataset.action)
  }

  if (valueNode) {
    return onNumberInput(valueNode.dataset.value)
  }
})

function onNumberInput(num) {
  $forNumbers.textContent += num
}

function doAction(action) {
  switch (action) {
    case 'sum':
      return sum()
    case 'multiply':
      return multiply()
    // ...
  }
}

function sum() {
  console.log('sum')
}

function multiply() {
  console.log('multiply')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles//styles.css" />
    <title>Caclucator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">
      <h1 id="header">MY CACLUCATOR</h1>
      <div class="calculator">
        <div id="digit-field"><span id="forNumbers"></span></div>
        <div id="buttons-field">
          <div class="row-1">
            <button class="calc-btns" data-action="AC">AC</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-action="+/-">+/-</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-action="percent">%</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-action="divide">/</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-2">
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="7">7</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="8">8</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="9">9</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-action="multiply">X</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-3">
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="4">4</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="5">5</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="6">6</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-action="minus">-</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-4">
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="1">1</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="2">2</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="3">3</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-action="sum">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-5">
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value="0">0</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-value=",">,</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" data-action="result">=</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Длинные имена часто используемых функций можно прятать в переменные ссылки:

   let gebi = function(id) {return document.getElementById(id)};
2. Слушалки не обязательно вешать вручную(можно попробовать циклы).
3. Слушалки не обязательно вешать прямо в коде js, можно использовать старый добрый dHTML, например так:

   <button class="calc-btns" id="seven" **ONCLICK='forNumbers.textContent += "7";'**>7
4. Есть кнопки инпуты, если не требуется вешать слушалку клика на кучу разношерстного контента(смесь из текста, тегов и картинок), желательно использовать их.

   <input type='button' value='1' **ONCLICK='forNumbers.textContent += "1";'**/>

```js
let digitsField = document.getElementById("digit-field");
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #7bb9ff;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.calculator {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#digit-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

#buttons-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.row-1, .row-2, .row-3, .row-4, .row-5 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 147px;
}

.calc-btns{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(157, 255, 206);
  font-size: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.calc-btns:hover{
  background-color: orange;
}

#forNumbers {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles//styles.css" />
    <title>Caclucator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">
      <h1 id="header">MY CACLUCATOR</h1>
      <div class="calculator">
        <div id="digit-field"><span id="forNumbers"></span></div>
        <div id="buttons-field">
          <div class="row-1">
            <button class="calc-btns" id="AC">AC</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="plusMinus">+/-</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="percent">%</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="divide">/</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-2">
            <input class="calc-btns" type='button' value='7' id='seven' ONCLICK='forNumbers.textContent += "7";'/>
            <input class="calc-btns" type='button' value='8' id='eight' ONCLICK='forNumbers.textContent += "8";'/>
            <input class="calc-btns" type='button' value='9' id='nine' ONCLICK='forNumbers.textContent += "9";'/>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="multiple">X</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-3">
            <input class="calc-btns" type='button' value='4' id='four' ONCLICK='forNumbers.textContent += "4";'/>
            <input class="calc-btns" type='button' value='5' id='five' ONCLICK='forNumbers.textContent += "5";'/>
            <input class="calc-btns" type='button' value='6' id='six' ONCLICK='forNumbers.textContent += "6";'/>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="minus">-</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-4">
            <button class="calc-btns" id="one">1</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="two">2</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="three">3</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="plus">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="row-5">
            <button class="calc-btns" id="zero">0</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="comma">,</button>
            <button class="calc-btns" id="equal">=</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Первый пункт, такую фигню серьезно кто-то делает?

Comment: авторы jQuery в качестве ответа сгодятся?)